# Any easy way to disable ads during development?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I am working on websites that will contain adds. However, I don't want these ads to be displayed during development.

Is there any easy way to disable the Javascript code generated by Google adsense? A flag for example? Should I fiddle something in JQuery document ready? Looking for a clean and easy solution. Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You may break your code and not know that your ads are affected.  Leave your ads on in development!  Don't worry about false impressions... Google is pretty keen on the fact that you load your page over and over again, and will start serving "free" ads, such as ads for Google services and products.

Comment: Google is very sensitive and pretty unilateral when it kicks out people. I just don't wanna take risks.

Comment: It's not a risk if you don't click the ads.  Sure, if you go around clicking ads, you are going to have a problem.  Visiting your site yourself isn't what is going to get your AdSense account shut down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely could wrap the Adsense JavaScript in a conditional statement, and set a flag yourself at the top of your document if you wanted; just be sure to strip it out in your build process, or whenever you're ready to ship your code.

While this is technically possible, I would probably suggest against it. I wouldn't worry too much about screwing up your reporting or anything - as was pointed out in the comments on your question, Google isn't exactly new at this; they can determine when it's a good time to show money-making advertisements, and when it's a good time to just toss in some fillers.

Please note that I do not represent Google, and I cannot say what activity will have your account(s) with them suspended. If you wish to protect yourself from accidental clicks, I would suggest you go ahead and disable the ads while in development. Better safe than sorry.